# Mongo: $exists in Pipeline $lookup not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

My two collections are :

---

product_category

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fca496b61e8a83e5cd0fb01"),
    "category_id" : "1",
    ...
}
```

---

product

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60684610f8f81d0013ce776d"),
    "primary_parent_category" : "1653",
    ...
}
```

---

Using localfield and foreignfield in $lookup, I can attain the expected result.

```
db.getCollection('product_category').aggregate([
    {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "product",
        "localField": "category_id",
        "foreignField": "primary_parent_category",
        "as": "products"
    }
    },
//     { "$match": { "products": { $exists: true, $not: { $size: 0 } } }},
    { "$match": { "products": { $exists: true, $ne: [] } }},
    {
    "$project":{
        "child_categories": 0,
        "featured_products": 0,
        "related_brands": 0,
        "child_category_names": 0
    }
    }
])
```

The above works fine, but I have to make use of the pipeline model in $lookup for another use case(for adding $geoNear). The aggregate query is as below.

```
db.getCollection('product_category').aggregate([
    {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "product",
        "let": { "category_id": "$category_id" },
        "pipeline": [
             { "$match": { "product": { $exists: true, $ne: [] } }},      
             {
                 "$project":{
                     "child_categories": 0,
                     "featured_products": 0,
                     "related_brands": 0,
                     "child_category_names": 0
                 }
             }
        ],
        "as": "products"
    }
    }
])
```

This is not working as expected and returns a whole lot of entries. $exists in $match is not getting properly executed.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the `$match` in `lookup` `pipeline` is expecting `product` field to exists, I doubt it exists. also, I don't see comparison on `category_id`

Comment: you missed match condition for category_id in pipeline, `{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$category_id", "$primary_parent_category"] } } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @turivishal, you have to make use of the `$expr` operator inside the `$match` within the pipeline parameter. You have to do this wherever you are trying to reference a temporary MongoDB variable using `$$`.

```
{
  $match: {
    {
      $expr: {"$eq": ["$$<VAR-NAME-IN-LET>", "$<FOREIGN-KEY-IN-TARGET-COL>"]}
    }
  }
}
```

```
db.getCollection('product_category').aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "product",
      "let": { "category_id": "$category_id" },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              { $eq: [ "$primary_parent_category",  "$$category_id" ] },
            }
            "product": { 
              $exists: true,
              $ne: [],
            },
          }
        },      
        {
          "$project":{
              "child_categories": 0,
              "featured_products": 0,
              "related_brands": 0,
              "child_category_names": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "products"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: hhharsha36 turivishal sidgate Thanks for the responses. I tried this method, but it is still returning a lot of records. in fact the behaviour is like the first query having localfield and foreignfield with match statement omitted. I suspect this behaviour might be due to what sidgate mentioned about the product variable not present in the pipeline stage. Any thoughts?

Comment: It might be a possibility. Please share the complete masked version of sample inputs and expected output so that I can help.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way was a combination of what @hhharsha36 and @turivishal mentioned. I had to move the match query for $exist after $lookup block, with variable mapping match block intact.

```
db.getCollection('product_category').aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "product",
      "let": { "category_id": "$category_id" },
      "pipeline": [
    {
      "$match": {
        "$expr": 
          { "$eq": [ "$primary_parent_category",  "$$category_id" ] },
      }},
    {
      "$project":{
          "child_categories": 0,
          "featured_products": 0,
          "related_brands": 0,
          "child_category_names": 0
      }
    }
      ],
      "as": "products"
    }
  },
  { "$match": 
      { "products": 
      { 
          "$exists": true,
          "$ne": [],
      } 
      } 
   },
])
```